# Vietnamese characters are garbled after import

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I exported a table in Oracle (which has Vietnamese text) from Dataserver A:

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.VN8VN3
exp system/123 BUFFER=64000 FILE=/tmp/export.dmp TABLES=(USERS.AREA) GRANTS=N INDEXES=NO ROWS=Y
```

And then, I try to import `export.dmp` to Dataserver B:

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.VN8VN3
imp system/123 BUFFER=64000 FILE=/tmp/export.dmp indexes=n grants=n constraints=n statistics=none ignore=y full=y
```

But, the field `ID_ISSUE_PLACE` was garbled.

[image]

And this is the screenshot which I operated in B.
I used the same command to export  two tables on A, but after I executed imp command on B,the result is like this! The field COMMENTS in table1 is correct, but the filed NAME in table2  is incorrect.

How to solve this problem?
[image: Screenshot.jpg]

Comment: that's a screenshot of Oracle SQL Developer, yes? Make sure the Preferences > Code Editor > Font is set to something that supports the characters you're trying to display in your query results

Comment: What is the character set of database B? Does it support Vietnamese characters?

Comment: The database A (source data)character set is : AMERICAN_AMERICA.VN8VN3

Comment: @Tom, I don't think so. Run `SELECT * 
    FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
    WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');` on Database B.

Comment: Dear @Wernfried Domscheit,I have exec the sql command , the result is NLS_CHARACTERSET:VN8VN3 ; NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET:
AL16UTF16 . There's somthing wrong?

Comment: No that's fine. How are these values on database A?

Comment: Dear @Wernfried Domscheit ,I have just tested on the database A,the result is the same as B .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows, and you are using SQL*Plus - it may be as simple as using the proper character set in the COMMAND window. In my case, I have the command `$chcp 1252` in my glogin.sql, but from within the session you can do the same with `host chcp 1252`. This changes the "codepage" (character mapping) to 1252, Microsoft's name for the character set it uses for graphical programs.

For Vietnamese, perhaps the right codepage is not 1252. Take a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html (and bookmark it for future reference); if I am reading it right, the correct codepage for Vietnamese is 1258.

So: Type `host chcp 1258` at the SQL*Plus console and see if it helps. If it does, add `$chcp 1258` to your glogin.sql.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - You may be right, but it is also possible that he uses a "terminal" connection to the database to do those manipulations in UNIX on the server, but the "local" session is in Windows (even from the same computer). Unrelated: I believe you are the one who taught me how to do this from within the SQL\*Plus session in the first place!

Comment: I have already set chcp on windows,but it does't  work.So I exec sqlplus on dataserver B. please see the screenshot above.

Comment: Dear @mathguy  , the second pictrue is the screenshot on B with sqlplus.

Comment: @Tom - Are you familiar with the `DUMP()` function? It is used to check what is actually stored in the database. For example: `select dump('tip') from dual` will return the stored values for the letters t, i and p, You can use this to see if the characters stored in the database are the correct ones. If they aren't, then the insertion of data INTO the db may have used the incorrect character set; in that case you can't do anything to see the correct characters. You will have to fix the stored data.

Comment: @Tom - Another example: the table `dual` (present in every Oracle db) has only one column, `dummy`, with only one row with the value `X`. `select dummy, dump(dummy) from dual;` returns `X  Typ=1 Len=1: 88`. This repeats the value (`X`) and the dump info: `Typ=1` means VARCHAR2, the length is 1 character, and the code of letter `X` in the database character set is `88`.

Comment: @Tom - Another example: the table `dual` (present in every Oracle db) has only one column, `dummy`, with only one row with the value `X`. `select dummy, dump(dummy) from dual;` returns `X  Typ=1 Len=1: 88`. This repeats the value (`X`) and the dump info: `Typ=1` means VARCHAR2, the length is 1 character, and the code of letter `X` in the database character set is `88`. Now: choose a name that shows correctly in one db but wrong in the other db, and run `dump()` on the name FROM THE TABLE (like I illustrated here with `dual`) in both databases. Do you get the same result?